# Extract from dynamic JSON response with Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to extract the 'avail' value from the JSON output that look like this.

```
{
    "result": {
        "code": 100,
        "message": "Command Successful"
    },
    "domains": {
        "yolotaxpayers.com": {
            "avail": false,
            "tld": "com",
            "price": "49.95",
            "premium": false,
            "backorder": true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `['avail']` value is under `["domains"]["domain_name"]` and I can't figure out how to get the domain name.

You have my spider below. The first part works fine, but not the second one.

```
import scrapy
import json
from whois.items import WhoisItem

class whoislistSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "whois_list"
    start_urls = []
    f = open('test.txt', 'r')
    global lines
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    def __init__(self):
        for line in lines:
            self.start_urls.append('http://www.example.com/api/domain/check/%s/com' % line)

    def parse(self, response):
        for line in lines:
            jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
            item = WhoisItem()
            domain_name = list(jsonresponse['domains'].keys())[0]
            item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
            item["domain"] = domain_name
            yield item
```

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are only expecting one result per response:

```
domain_name = list(jsonresponse['domains'].keys())[0]
item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
```

This will work even if there is a mismatch between the domain in the file "test.txt" and the domain in the result.

Comment: Thanks @Dean 
It works fine, but it gets into a kind of a loop. 
For 17 checked domains, I got 289 results with a lot of duplicates. Do you have any idea how to escape this loop?

Comment: @CristianCalin Seems that in your `parse` function you are adding to the list of domains (and also in init), this is possibly the source of the infinite loop.

Comment: I moved the list of domains up in the `class` and defined `lines` as global, but still the same loop.

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated code. This might have something to do with the way scrapy checks for duplicate urls.

Comment: Why are you adding all the domains to "allowed_domains", do you mean to send the crawler to them? Maybe it considers a WhoisItem as the next stage of crawling...

Comment: I have deleted those lines and updated the code, but unfortunately I have the same result. @DeanFenster

Comment: @CristianCalin Could you add the code for the `WhoisItem` you are using? either here or on a follow-up question (since we are getting off-topic)

Comment: Thank you @DeanFenster I have posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315087/scrapy-returns-more-results-than-expected

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it tries to get the value by the `"('%s.com' % line)"` key.

You need to do the string formatting correctly:

```
domain_name = "%s.com" % line.strip()
item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. It worked, but now I'm getting `item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
KeyError: 'qqqqq.com'` I think it's quotes related, right?

Answer (score 0):

To get the domain name from above json response you can use list comprehension , e.g:

### domain_name = [x for x in jsonresponse.values()[0].keys()]

To get the "avail" value use same method, e.g:

### avail = [x["avail"] for x in jsonresponse.values()[0].values() if "avail" in x]

to get the values in string format you should call it by index 0 e.g:

**domain_name[0]** and **avail[0]** because list comprehension  results stored in list type variable.

[More info on list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)