# Scrapy returns more results than expected

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

*This is a continuation of the question: [Extract from dynamic JSON response with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310986/extract-from-dynamic-json-response-with-scrapy)*

I have a Scrapy spider that extract values from a JSON response. It works well, extract the right values, but somehow it enters in a loop and returns more results than expected (duplicate results).

For example for 17 values provided in `test.txt` file it returns `289` results, that means `17 times more` than expected.

**Spider content below:**

```
import scrapy
import json
from whois.items import WhoisItem

class whoislistSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "whois_list"
    start_urls = []
    f = open('test.txt', 'r')
    global lines
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    def __init__(self):
        for line in lines:
            self.start_urls.append('http://www.example.com/api/domain/check/%s/com' % line)

    def parse(self, response):
        for line in lines:
            jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
            item = WhoisItem()
            domain_name = list(jsonresponse['domains'].keys())[0]
            item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
            item["domain"] = domain_name
            yield item
```

**items.py content below**

```
import scrapy

class WhoisItem(scrapy.Item):
    avail = scrapy.Field()
    domain = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py below**

```
class WhoisPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Thank you in advance for all the replies.

Comment: Is there a pipelines.py file?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the code inside pipelines.py file `class WhoisPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse` function should be like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    item = WhoisItem()
    domain_name = list(jsonresponse['domains'].keys())[0]
    item["avail"] = jsonresponse["domains"][domain_name]["avail"]
    item["domain"] = domain_name
    yield item
```

Notice that I removed the `for` loop.

What was happening: for every single response you would loop and parse it 17 times. (Therefore resulting in 17*17 records)

Comment: Works like a charm! You are awesome @DeanFenster Thank you very much!